# Sort order within a Table Matrix in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need some help with a Table Matrix/Drill through report, sort order.  My report looks something like this

```
Account      Name         JNumber       AmountNet  
0133266      New Jets                   12469.86
```

The AmountNet is a Sum of the drill through data

You click on the report `Name` field and it opens up as follows

```
Account    Name       JNumber     AmountNet  
0133266    New Jets    1            900.00  
                       2            163.86  
                       3             90.00  
                       4          10506.00  
                       Total      12469.86
```

What I want to do is when the report is in its original state i.e. before you click any of the names to see how the `AmountNet` is made up, is order it by the `AmountNet` column descending.  If there is any other information that you need please let me know.

Comment: For future reference, take a look at what I did to format this. An empty line and then indenting each line by 4 spaces causes the font to be monospaced

Answer (score 13):

You need to change the sort order of the groups. Right click on the group and get into the Group Properties. Use the Sorting section to sort by an expression:

```
=SUM(Fields!AmountNet.Value)
```

MSDN has [this to say](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220417.aspx#Sorting):

> **Tablix data region group.** Set sort expressions for each group,
>   including the details group, to control the sort order of group
>   instances. For example, for the details group, you control the order
>   of the detail rows. For a child group, you control the order of group
>   instances for the child group within the parent group. By default,
>   when you create a group, the sort expression is set to the group
>   expression and to ascending order.

Comment: Hi Jamie, Thanks very much for the assistance but I am afraid that it is making no difference, I have gone through and made sure that there are no sort orders on any of the other columns so there can be no conflict but its making no difference.  Dont suppose you have any other suggestions.  Thanks P

Comment: Hi Jamie, please ignore my last message you were spot on, I was just adding it to the wrong section, one of those days.  Thanks again for the help and the pointers on formatting.  PJD